# Can't access value of [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form style="clear: left;" id="form">
            <input type="text" id="name" disabled="true" value="/path/to/device">
            <select name="Mode" id="mode">
                <option value="GEN">Generate Data</option>
                <option value="XBEE">Receive via XBEE</option>
                <option value="SD">Read SD card</option>
            </select>

            <input type="text" id="path" disabled="true" value="/path/to/device">
            <select name="Baud Rate" id="baud" disabled="true">
                <option value="9600">9600</option>
            </select>

            <button type="button" id="control">Start</button>
        </form>

        <textarea rows="50" cols="80" id="log" maxlength="1000">
        </textarea>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/dataLogger/js/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/dataLogger/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my javascript:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var modeSelect = document.getElementById("mode");
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var path = document.getElementById("path");
var baud = document.getElementById("baud");
var submit = document.getElementById("control");

console.log(name);
console.log(name.value);
console.log(path);
console.log(path.value);
```

When I run this code, the following is the output:

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
undefined
input#path
/path/to/device
```

I'm not sure why the second input works, but the first one doesn't I've tried using other selectors like `getElementsByTagName` but that gave the same results. Any ideas?

Comment: It's working fine :) [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rure96fh/)

Comment: What did you expect? If you're retrieving an element, isn't it just logic to get one?

Comment: @Teemu Well... 1) The two elements are clearly different in the format returned. One returns "[object HtmlInput]" and one returns "input#path" isn't it logic that the format would be the same. and 2) Both have values. Isn't it logic that I should be able to retrieve both values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unaware that `name` was a reserved word in Javascript. Changing `var name` to something else fixed the issue.